# Grepping Key-Value Pairs from Brackets in Perl

Tags: perl, grep

What if I have a string that consists of tuples in brackets and I would like to get the maximum value out of the tuple in Perl? Example:

Input: [everyday,32][hoho,16][toodledum,128][echigo,4]

Output: 128

Comment: Do you care about all the other values? Would you need to use "toodledum" later on?

Answer (score 5):

If you want all of the data, you could put it into a hash first.

```
my %data = $str =~ /\[([^,]+),([^\]]+)\]/g;
use List::Util qw'max';
my($max) = max(values %data);
print "max: $max\n";
```

If you want to know which key(s) have that number, you could then use a `grep`

```
print "key: $_\n" for grep { $data{$_} == $max } keys %data;
```

If you really only need the max value:

```
use List::Util qw'max';
print max $str =~ /\[[^,]+,([^\]]+)\]/g;
```

Comment: What do the carrot signs mean?

Comment: Normally [] says to match any one of the characters in between the brackets (e.g. a[bc]d would match abd, acd but not abcd).  The '^' negates it, so that a[^bc]d would match aed, but not abd.

Answer (score 2):

For the input provided:

```
$input = "[everyday,32][hoho,16][toodledum,128][echigo:4]";
$max = -Inf;
foreach ($input =~ /\[\w+,(\d+)\]/g) {
  $max = $_ if $max < $_;
}
print $max;
```

Use `([^\]]+)` instead of `(\d+)` if the values might be floating point values.

Comment: I'd suggest always declaring an iterator variable -- i.e. foreach my $value ($input ....) -- rather than depending on $_, as it can sometimes change underneath you in unexpected ways.  Likely not in this case, but it's a good habit to get into.